# how to get the return code of the binary sftp when i'am Use expect in bash script to provide password to SFTP Command

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp, expect

I'm trying to use expect in an bash script to provide the SFTP password and put other commands.
I'am try to get the return code of binary SFTP .

My test script :

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
HOST=$2
PASSWD=$3
PORT=$4
FILEIN=$5
FILEOUT=$6
ACTION=$7

CR_FTP=`/usr/bin/expect <<EOF | tee -a log.log
spawn sftp -v -oPort=$PORT $USER@$HOST
expect "password:"
send "$PASSWD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "ls\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "$ACTION $FILEIN $FILEOUT\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF`

echo " -------------------- $CR_FTP --------------------------"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
send "bye\r"
expect eof
set details [wait]
puts "sftp exit status=[lindex $details 3]"
EOF`
```

See http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html